# Align section title and subtitle to outside border on twoside template

Tags: align, titlesec

I have a problem aligning the section-title to the outside on a twoside template. As seen in the screenshot below, my section title contains not only the title (which appears in the toc) but also a subtitle. While the alignment of the title works perfect, the subtitle always aligns to the left. I tried raggedleft and raggedright as can be seen in the code below, flushright and a solution with `<blank line> \hspace*{\fill} <text>` but nothing works for me.
[image]

My code:

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\color{ColAccent}\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter\fontsize{36pt}{43pt}\selectfont}
    {\thesection}
    {0.5em}
    {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,page=even}
    {\color{ColAccent}\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright\fontsize{28pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
    {\thesubsection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,page=odd}
    {\color{ColAccent}\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft\fontsize{28pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
    {\thesubsection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\color{Black}\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{16pt}{22pt}\selectfont}
    {\thesubsubsection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\color{Black}\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{14pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
    {\thesubsubsubsection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
    
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2][]{
\ifoddpage
    \subsection{#2}
    {\sffamily\raggedleft\textbf{#1}}\\
\else
  \subsection{#2}
    {\sffamily\raggedright\textbf{#1}}\\
\fi
}
```

Comment: Can you include a complete, compilable minimum example? Also, your screen shot seems to show the subtitle (directly underneath the title), aligned to the right on the right hand page. Is this not what you want? It may also help in preparing the screen shot to clearly indicate which part of the text is the title and which part is the subtitle and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't have the subtitle environment you're using, I took advantage of the formatting of `paragraph`,  as a substitute.

In this code you can change the alignment of the subtitles by modifying the definitions of `\paragraphformatO` or `\paragraphformatE` and using `\raggedleft` or `\raggedright`.

[image: c]

**All subtitles left aligned**

[image: e]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[left=4.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec} % format titles

\newcommand{\paragraphformatO}[1]{%
    \parbox[b]{0.6\textwidth}{\raggedright#1}}

%\newcommand{\paragraphformatE}[1]{% right align <<<<<<<<<<
%   \parbox[b]{0.6\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\newcommand{\paragraphformatE}[1]{% left align  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \parbox[b]{0.6\textwidth}{\raggedright#1}}


\newcommand{\sectionformatE}[1]{%
{\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1pc-\marginparwidth-\evensidemargin\relax][r]{\thesubsection\hspace*{0.5em}#1}}}
}

%%  \titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
\titleformat{name=\subsection, page=odd}[block]
{\filright\color{cyan}\fontsize{28pt}{30pt}\selectfont\bf\sffamily} % format subsection odd 
{\thesubsection}% format label
{0.5em} 
{}%

\titleformat{name=\subsection, page=even}[block]
{\color{cyan}\fontsize{28pt}{30pt}\selectfont\bf\sffamily} % format subsection even
{}
{0.0em} 
{\sectionformatE}%


\titlespacing*{name=\subsection, page=odd}
{-4pc} % left
{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex} % before
{1.5ex minus .1ex} %after

\titlespacing*{name=\subsection, page=even}
{14pc} % left
{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex} % before
{1.5ex minus .1ex} %after

%%  \titlespacing*{⟨command⟩}{⟨left⟩}{⟨before-sep⟩}{⟨after-sep⟩}[⟨right-sep⟩]   
\newlength{\rightsep}
\setlength{\rightsep}{18.5pc}

\titleformat{name=\paragraph,page=even}
{\color{black}\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
{}% no label
{0em}
{\paragraphformatE}%

\titleformat{name=\paragraph,page=odd}
{\color{black}\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
{}% no label
{0em}
{\paragraphformatO}%


\titlespacing*{name=\paragraph, page=even}
{\rightsep} % right sep
{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex} % before
{1.5ex minus .1ex} %after

\titlespacing*{name=\paragraph, page=odd}
{-4pc} % left sep
{0.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex} % before
{1.5ex minus .1ex} %after

\begin{document}
    
\sffamily   
\setcounter{section}{6}    

\subsection{Subsec one}
\paragraph{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of  the things in themselves.}

\kant[1] 

\subsection{Subsec two}
\paragraph{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of  the things in themselves.}

\kant[1]    
\newpage

\subsection{Subsec three}
\paragraph{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of  the things in themselves.}

\kant[2]

\subsection{Subsec four}
\paragraph{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of  the things in themselves.}

\kant[9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot.